# Are there any examples of the Esri GeoPortal REST API in use?

Tags: rest, metadata, geoportal

Are they any public examples of sites built on top of the Esri GeoPortal's [REST API](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/REST-API-Syntax)?

I would like to use the back-end functionality of the GeoPortal to manage the metadata, but serve it up using a custom front-end.

Before I undertake this task I'm interested to see whether anyone has successfully achieved this.

Thanks.

Comment: Older Geoportal implementations can be configured to support newer versions of ArcGIS. We also test the Geoportal add-ons, such as the CSW clients and the Publish client, to ensure compatibility with the latest version of ArcGIS for Desktop. Please contact portal@esri.com http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal/common-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any examples written on top of the GeoPortal Server REST API - so I wrote one. Seems to work well ;)

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.2.2 does use the REST API.

Geportal REST API:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/geoportal/index.php?title=REST_API_Syntax

Check out these sites. I'm not sure if any are running 1.2.2 but are probably not too far back:

http://geo.data.gov/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page

http://www.ga.gov.au/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page

http://wygl.wygisc.org/wygeolib/catalog/main/home.page

DG

Comment: Thanks @DLG. By "examples of sites built on top of" GeoPortal I was hoping to find something stand-alone which uses just the REST API, not the GeoPortal front-end. Any ideas?

Comment: I re-wrote the question to make it clearer what I'm asking, and referring to the correct documentation

Comment: Are you looking for something that provides Geoportal administration that is not the standard Geoportal Java front end?  Perhaps search for any Silverlight, Flash, or JavaScript API sites that interact with the Geportal REST API.  I've worked with the Silverlight viewer provided with the Geoportal install but that is designed for searching and not for administration.  The ESRI web site directs to SourceForge for the Geoportal software so I'm not sure if Github has all you would need although I do see that Martin Hogeweg edits that site.  Confusing.

Comment: Exactly, I'm looking to see whether anyone's written their own front-end. If not, I guess I'll be a pioneer...

Answer (score 1):

The INSPIRE Portal of the Grand-Duchy of Luxembourg is build on top Geoportal:

http://inspire.geoportail.lu/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page